# How did $DT^{-1}(x,y)=(DT(x,y))^{-1}$ followed from the chain rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The book, Vector Calculus, claims that, under certain assumptions, the Jacobian  $$
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=\left(
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}
\right)^{-1}
$$

The book began the simple proof by stating

> If the transformation matrix $T(u,v)=(x,y) $ then $(u,v)=T^{-1}(x,y)$. It follows from the chain rule that $$DT^{-1}(x,y)=(DT(x,y))^{-1}$$ The proof of the claim follows from applying the property of determinants to the equation above

I can't understand how the above conclusion is easily reached using chain rule alone. It states that the derivative matrix of the inverse transformation $T$ is equal to the inverse of the derivative of $T$. Please give me hints or explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at what is written below. This is another version of getting the answer. First let $u=\phi(r,s), v=\psi(r,s)$, so:
$$
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(r,s)}=\begin{vmatrix}
x_r & x_s\\
y_r& y_s
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
x_uu_r+x_vv_r & x_vu_s+x_vv_s\\
y_uu_r+y_vv_r & y_vu_s+y_vv_s
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
x_u & x_v\\
y_u& y_v
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
u_r & u_s\\
v_r& v_s
\end{vmatrix}=
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(r,s)}
$$
Now as second step assume $r=x,s=y$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** apply the chain rule to $T\circ T^{-1} = \operatorname{id}$ and $T^{-1}\circ T = \operatorname{id}$.

**More detailed answer:**

The chain rule applied on the first equality above yields $DT\circ D(T^{-1}) = D\operatorname{id} = \operatorname{id}$.

Similarly the second equation yields $D(T^{-1})\circ DT = D\operatorname{id} = \operatorname{id}$.

This yields $(DT)^{-1} = D(T^{-1})$, which is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will start from there